# Combining 8 Complex Queries from 7 Tables into one Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to create a complex query by combining 8 queries from 7 different tables into one query to create a full report. I can do basic combinations, but this query is getting the better of me. I have browsed the web for complex join queries, but I am not coming right...

All the tables are linked via 'plant_id', but some of the data are the latest entry, some calculated entries for the current month, etc. the queries below, all work perfectly on their own, but I have to combine them into the following:

[ plant_id, plant_make_id, plant_model ],[ current_plant_hrs, plant_hours_total ],[ plant_error_report ],[ plant_service_next ],[ plant_status_ddl_id ],[ total diesel used, consumption ],[ location_id ]

Below a breakdown + the individual queries:-

```
1 plant [ plant_id, plant_make_id, plant_model ],       
SELECT `plant_id`,`plant_make_id`,`plant_model`
 FROM `plant`

2 plant_hrs [ current_plant_hrs, plant_hours_total  ],           
A
SELECT `plant_hrs_stop`
FROM `plant_hrs` s1
WHERE `plant_hrs_date`=(SELECT MAX(s2.`plant_hrs_date`)
FROM `plant_hrs` s2
WHERE s1.`plant_id` = s2.`plant_id`)
ORDER BY `plant_id`
B
SELECT (MAX(`plant_hrs_stop`)- MIN(`plant_hrs_start`) )total_hrs
FROM`plant_hrs` 
WHERE MONTH(`plant_hrs_date`)= MONTH( CURRENT_DATE ) 
GROUP BY`plant_id`

3 plant_error [ plant_error_report ],               
SELECT `plant_error_report`
FROM `plant_error` s1
WHERE `plant_error_date`=(SELECT MAX(s2.`plant_error_date`)
FROM `plant_error` s2
WHERE s1.`plant_id` = s2.`plant_id`)
ORDER BY `plant_id`

4 plant_service [ plant_service_next ],             
SELECT `plant_service_hrs` , `plant_service_next`
FROM `plant_service` s1
WHERE `plant_service_date`=(SELECT MAX(s2.`plant_service_date`)
FROM `plant_service` s2
WHERE s1.`plant_id` = s2.`plant_id`)
ORDER BY `plant_id`

5 plant_status [ plant_status_ddl_id ],              
SELECT `plant_status_ddl_id`
FROM `plant_status`
WHERE `plant_status_date` = ( CURRENT_DATE ) - 1
GROUP BY `plant_id

6 diesel [ total diesel used, consumption ],            // 'plant_id = diesel_vehicle_no' 
SELECT (SUM(`diesel_qty`) )total_d
FROM`diesel` 
WHERE MONTH(`diesel_date`)= MONTH( CURRENT_DATE ) 
GROUP BY `diesel_vehicle_no`

7 plant_location [ location_id ]                    
SELECT `location_id` FROM `plant_location`
ORDER BY `plant_id`
```

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: Have you considered using a stored proc? With 8 complex queries it may be easier to separate and manage within a proc than one large SQL statement.

Answer (score 3):

OK, let's take a look at this: We will start by simply combining your queries - even though there will be much room for optimization.

Queries 1 and 7 do sort of nothing - so we will use their base tables instead - the rest we take 'as is'

```
SELECT
  `plant`.`plant_id`,
  IFNULL(`qry2A`.`plant_hrs_stop`,''),
  IFNULL(`qry2B`.`total_hrs`,''),
  IFNULL(`qry3`.`plant_error_report`,''),
  IFNULL(`qry4`.`plant_service_next`,''),
  IFNULL(`qry5`.`plant_status_ddl_id`,''),
  IFNULL(`qry6`.`total_d`,''),
  IFNULL(`plant_location`.`location_id`'')
FROM
  -- Query 1: Use table
  `plant`
  -- Query 2A: Use as-is, but with the plant_id field and without the ORDER BY
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `plant_hrs_stop`, s1.`plant_id` AS `plant_id`
    FROM `plant_hrs` s1
    WHERE `plant_hrs_date`=(SELECT MAX(s2.`plant_hrs_date`)
    FROM `plant_hrs` s2
    WHERE s1.`plant_id` = s2.`plant_id`)
  ) AS `qry2A` ON `plant`.`plant_id`=`qry2A`.`plant_id`
  -- Query 2B: Use as-is, but with the plant_id field
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT (MAX(`plant_hrs_stop`)- MIN(`plant_hrs_start`) ) AS total_hrs, `plant_id`
    FROM`plant_hrs` 
    WHERE MONTH(`plant_hrs_date`)= MONTH( CURRENT_DATE ) 
    GROUP BY`plant_id`
  ) AS `qry2B` ON `plant`.`plant_id`=`qry2B`.`plant_id`
  -- Query 3: Use as-is, but with the plant_id field and without the ORDER BY
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `plant_error_report`,s1.`plant_id` AS `plant_id`
    FROM `plant_error` s1
    WHERE `plant_error_date`=(SELECT MAX(s2.`plant_error_date`)
    FROM `plant_error` s2
    WHERE s1.`plant_id` = s2.`plant_id`)
  ) AS `qry3` ON `plant`.`plant_id`=`qry3`.`plant_id`
  -- Query 4: Use as-is, but with the plant_id field and without the ORDER BY
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `plant_service_hrs` , `plant_service_next`,s1.`plant_id` AS `plant_id`
    FROM `plant_service` s1
    WHERE `plant_service_date`=(SELECT MAX(s2.`plant_service_date`)
    FROM `plant_service` s2
    WHERE s1.`plant_id` = s2.`plant_id`)
  ) AS `qry4` ON `plant`.`plant_id`=`qry4`.`plant_id`
  -- Query 5: Use as-is, but with the plant_id field
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `plant_status_ddl_id`,`plant_id`
    FROM `plant_status`
    WHERE `plant_status_date` = ( CURRENT_DATE ) - 1
    GROUP BY `plant_id
  ) AS `qry5` ON `plant`.`plant_id`=`qry5`.`plant_id`
  -- Query 6: Use as-is, but with the plant_id field
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT (SUM(`diesel_qty`) ) AS total_d, `diesel_vehicle_no` AS `plant_id`
    FROM`diesel` 
    WHERE MONTH(`diesel_date`)= MONTH( CURRENT_DATE ) 
    GROUP BY `diesel_vehicle_no`
  ) AS `qry6` ON `plant`.`plant_id`=`qry6`.`plant_id`
  -- Query 7: Use table
  LEFT JOIN `plant_location` ON `plant`.`plant_id`=`plant_location`.`plant_id`
ORDER BY
  `plant`.`plant_id`
```

**Edit**: Used LEFT instead of INNER joins as suggested by @LuisSiquot

**Edit**: Added IFNULL() after request in comments

Comment: I do suggest LEFT JOIN becouse perhaps not all querys return data for each pant_id

Comment: @LuisSiquot Excellent catch! I assumed all data to exist, but ofcourse this assumption is highly suspect. Editing my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I did think it bit too easy, I only get three fields now (we have a total of 38 plant), which makes me think that because some of the tables do not have details or data in them, the other plant dont show. How can I force each Plant to be displayed regardless if some of the other tables dont have data in them for those plant?

Comment: @LuisSiquot LEFT JOIN may very well solve my problem, but I have not worked with LEFT JOIN's before, a little help here would be appreciated. Please concider this: `plant`.`plant_id` will always have all the plant, but the rest of the tables may not always have data for a specific plant... regards, thanx a million for the help so far... Jay

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you, so very much... The query worked very well Just a last question on this:- how do I remove the "NULL" entries in the blank fields, so the user dont see the word "NULL" but rather a blank field?

Comment: JJ, check @Eugen edition of his anwser, because he has patch it with LEFT JOINs

Comment: the way to thank here is to "accept one anwser" and "upvote" as many as are useful to you. Also you can contribute anwsering to somebody else something. have a good day

Comment: @JJMorgan I edited my answer (use of `IFNULL()` in the field list) to supress all null-fields to an emty string. Adapt to your needs!

Comment: If you are using a database without ifnull(), then COALESCE(fieldname, '') will do the same thing and it is part of the ANSII standrad som most databases will have it available.

Comment: @HLGEM The question is tagged as `MySQL` - which is why I assumed existance of `IFNULL()`. Be advised, that `COALESCE()` isn't as ubiquituous as it should be.

Comment: I tweaked the script a little and wuala... it works perfectly. Thanx again you guys. The help is much appreciated... Jay

Comment: I just brought up coalesce for someone else who looks at this answer later and can't make it work in their own case.  I think you did a terrific job with solving the OPs problem.

Comment: @JJMorgan Could you share your tweaks with us? This site functions also as an encyclopedia, and your final solution might be of interest to future searchers.